# Get controller and action from url

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a unit test where I am testing my Laravel controller.  I am performing a POST to my controller action which will return a redirect with parameters.  How can take the redirect URL location and get the controller and action.  I am not concerned about the parameters, I only want to confirm that correct controller and action.

```
$crawler = $this->action('POST', 'ItemController@postItem', array(), $data);
$this->assertResponseStatus(302);
$redirecturl = $this->client->getResponse()->headers->get('Location');
// $redirecturl = http://localhost/item/{uid}/edit
// how do I get controller and action from url ???
// e.g. http://localhost/item/{uid}/edit = ItemController@getEdit from routes
```

Thanks.

Comment: then you need to follow a pattern in routes. such as `controller/actionName`

Comment: "then you need to follow a pattern in routes", that is my question, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction(); will get you the action name

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my understanding is that only gets the action from the current route, not the action from the route that matches the provided URL.